# Como uso robolectric no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, testes, testes-de-unidade

Olá, gostaria de saber como uso [robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) em meus projetos no Android Studio. Já tentei vários tutorias, mas nenhum foi de grande ajuda e a [documentação](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle#intellij--android-studio-support) dele não é muito clara.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, inclua o jar nas dependências do seu projeto.

Em seguida, use a anotação `RunWith` (diponível em JUnit4):

Exemplo:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class TesteRobolectric {
    @Test
    public void aplicacao() throws Exception {
        String appName = new RobolectricUso().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        assertThat(appName, equalTo("RobolectricUso"));
    }
}
```

O recomendado é usar o Maven com o [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/).

Mais usos veja [aqui](http://robolectric.org/quick-start/).